# Clonezilla to restore Ubuntu to partition dual boot with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, clonezilla

As the title suggests, it's a confusing one but let me elaborate.

I'd like to set up a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a 250GB SSD and would like to partition 110GB each to be used for each OS (roughly).

Currently, there is only Ubuntu installed on the hard drive which only has 40GB used.

I've tried cloning it with Clonezilla then formatting the full drive, creating two partitions and installing Windows 10 on one. I'm now stuck on trying to restore the Ubuntu image from Clonezilla to the other partition.

So my question is, can this even be done?

Can I restore the Clonezilla image to a separate partition? If so, how? Is there anything I need to take into consideration such as the original source disk being 250gb and now I'm restoring to a 110GB partition (although the data size is 40GB). Do I also have to do anything about grub?

Comment: You need to learn this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I've managed to shrink the Ubuntu volume, clone and restore using clonezilla to a partition. Problem is, it boots only to Windows 10 and Grub doesn't show up now. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this!

I already had Ubuntu installed, so I shrinked the drive down to given more space and created an ntfs partition. I then installed Win10 on there. Since the boot-up was replaced by Windows MBR, I then used the Ubuntu live USB to do a 'boot-repair' for the OS and install grub back. I can now chose any o/s to boot from now and  all working!

Thanks to this:

https://silentinfotech.com/blog/steps-to-install-windows-10-on-existing-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: The next time you visit this site remember to click the grey check mark next to your answer to accept it.